# Long Int literal - Invalid Syntax?

Tags: python, python-3.x, int, syntax-error, long-integer

The Python tutorial book I'm using is slightly outdated, but I've decided to continue using it with the latest version of Python to practice debugging. Sometimes there are a few things in the book's code that I learn have changed in the updated Python, and I'm not sure if this is one of them.

While fixing a program so that it can print longer factorial values, it uses a long int to solve the problem. The original code is as follows:

```
#factorial.py
#   Program to compute the factorial of a number
#   Illustrates for loop with an accumulator

def main():
    n = input("Please enter a whole number: ")
    fact = 1
    for factor in range(int(n), 0, -1):
        fact = fact * factor

    print("The factorial of ", n, " is ", fact)

main()
```

The long int version is as follows:

```
#factorial.py
#   Program to compute the factorial of a number
#   Illustrates for loop with an accumulator

def main():
    n = input("Please enter a whole number: ")
    fact = 1L
    for factor in range(int(n), 0, -1):
        fact = fact * factor

    print("The factorial of ", n, " is ", fact)

main()
```

But running the long int version of the program in the Python shell generates the following error:

```
>>> import factorial2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    import factorial2
  File "C:\Python34\factorial2.py", line 7
    fact = 1L
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: (Consider that the entire problem could have been demonstrated when trying and showing the result of `fact = 1L`; the rest of the code is just baggage for sake of the question)

Comment: @user2864740: but if you make the assumption that the Python 2 had a reason to add the `L` postfix, then perhaps the rest of the context was needed to determine how to translate its use to Python 3? The assumption is false, but someone new to Python 2 cannot know this.

Comment: @MartijnPieters It isn't needed to reproduce the problem. The problem is the provided code results in a syntax error. This can be reproduced with `fact = 1L` which will fail where the above fails that will fail as well.

Comment: @user2864740: yes, I know. That's not the point I am making. If the OP is trying to translate the code to Python 3, *what should they use instead* of `fact = 1L` here? For that, it could well have been that the context was significant.

Answer (score 31):

Just drop the `L`; **all** integers in Python 3 are long. What was `long` in Python 2 is now the standard `int` type in Python 3.

The original code doesn't have to use a long integer either; Python 2 switches to the `long` type transparently as needed *anyway*.

Note that all Python 2 support is shortly ending (no more updates after 2020/01/01), so at this point in time you'd be much better of switching tutorials and invest your time in learning Python 3. For beginner programmers I recommend [Think Python, 2nd edition](http://greenteapress.com/wp/think-python-2e/) as it is fully updated for Python 3 and freely available online. Or [pick any of the other Stack Overflow Python chatroom recommended books and tutorials](https://sopython.com/wiki/What_tutorial_should_I_read%3F)

If you must stick to your current tutorial, you could install a Python 2.7 interpreter instead, and work your way through the book without having to learn how to port Python 2 to Python 3 code first.  However, you'd then also have to learn how transition from Python 2 to Python 3 in addition.

Answer (score 1):

You just need remove `L`

```
fact = 1
```

Python 3.X integers support unlimited size in contrast to Python 2.X that has a separate type for long integers.