# seed = 5L in pyspark with Python 3 returns syntax error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyspark

I am migrating to python 3, (from python 2)

```
seed = 5L
model = ALS.train(trainingRDD, rank, seed=seed, iterations=iterations,
                  lambda_=regularizationParameter)
```

and the first line of the code above returns invalid syntax error.
How should I tune it in Python 3?
The error is:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
  File "<command-2039439267792266>", line 6
    seed = 5L
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Thanks! I think the answer below is what you need then! Python 3 only has a single int type, they dropped the "long int" and combined.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Long Int literal - Invalid Syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24249519/long-int-literal-invalid-syntax)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need remove `L`

```
seed = 5
```

Python 3.X integers support unlimited size in contrast to Python 2.X that has a separate type for long integers.